# ¿Cómo detener un socket en Python con interfaz gráfica?

Tags: python, socket

Estoy diseñando una interfaz en Python que me permita iniciar un socket si necesidad de estar arrancandolo desde la linea de comandos, ya tengo los botones y el paso de parametros para iniciar el socket, se inicia correctamente pero se me congela la interfaz y me es imposible hacer uso de los botones para cerrar el programa, a menos que mate el proceso funciona pero no es esa la idea, adjunto código principal:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *
from pymongo import MongoClient
import socket
import datetime

root = Tk()

dato = StringVar()
dato2 = IntVar()
dato3 = IntVar()
r = StringVar()

def startSocket(ipSocket=str(dato.get()), port=int(dato2.get()), callClient=int(dato3.get()), socket=socket):
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
    ## paramatros a base de datos ####

    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.bind((ipSocket, port))

    class client(Thread):

        # Método que inicia la escucha de "n" numero de clientes
        def __init__(self, socket, address):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.sock = socket
            self.addr = address
            self.start()

        # Método que recibe las peticiones y transforma los datos recibidos
        def run(self):
            while 1:
                valores = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

                ######## Lógica que empleo para descomponer una cadena y guardar la información############

        # Permite la escucha de n clientes
        socket.listen(callClient)
        print('Servidor escuchando')

        # Bucle que siempre se esta ejecutando y escuchando peticiones
        while True:
            conexion, addr = socket.accept()
            client(conexion, addr)
            conexion.close()

Label(root, text="Direccion IP:").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=dato).pack()

Label(root, text="Puerto:").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=dato2).pack()

Label(root, text="Clientes a escuchar:").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=dato3).pack()

Label(root, text="").pack()

Button(root, text="Iniciar servidor", command=startSocket).pack()

root.iconbitmap('socket.ico')
root.resizable(1,1)
root.mainloop()
```

Adicional a lo que tengo debo poner un boton para detener el socket, ese no tengo problema en ponerlo, el problema seria hacer que el socket deje de escuchar y que me permita hacer uso de dicho botón. Cabe aclarar que aún sin interfaz no he podido detener el socket haciendo uso de las teclas CTRL + C. Por si me lo preguntan, debo recibir datos de más de 1 cliente por el mismo socket, es por ello que siempre debo mantenerlo activo.

Answer (score 1):

Entre otros muchos errores que debe tener el código, este destaca especialmente por su originalidad:

```
def startSocket(ipSocket=str(dato.get()), port=int(dato2.get()), callClient=int(dato3.get()), socket=socket):
```

En Python un `def` es algo que se *ejecuta*. El resultado de la ejecución es que Python obtiene la *definición* de la función, y ya puedes empezar a ocuparla.

Pero ... en la definición tienes instrucciones, que Python va a ejecutar antes de empezar a procesar esa definición:

- `get` por cada parámetro.
- 'int' por cada `get`. Más vale que el usuario ingrese correctamente el valor, o el programa se cae al empezar.

Si quieres llamar a la función, antes tienes que pedir los valores por separado.

```
def startSocket(ipSocket, port, callCliente, socket):
    ...


ipSocket=str(dato.get())
port=int(dato2.get())
callClient=int(dato3.get())
startSocket(ipSocket, port, callCliente, socket)
```

Definir una clase dentro de una función, aunque legal y útil en ocasiones, aquí sólo agrega complejidad y confusión. Probablemente tampoco haga lo que creas.

Resumen: Hay que repensarlo.